# How do I optimize this query with whereHas?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-optimization

I was using this query to filter out stores with city and categories. It was working fine when I had around 1000 records in `stores` table. Now, when I have 5000 records it takes around 3-10 seconds to generate result.

A store belongs to multiple categories in my case.

How can I optimize this query using Eloquent orm or `DB::raw()`?

```
$stores = Store::where('city_id', $city_id)
        ->where('disabled', '0')
        ->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($category_id){
            $q->where('category_id', '=', $category_id);
        })
        ->orderBy('rating','DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your tables? Hard to tell 100% from the query in eloquent form, but this _should_ generate reasonable SQL.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, both of the tables have indexes. Just confirmed by running this command `SHOW INDEX FROM stores;`.

Comment: Take a look on this issue it may help you and specially comment of kaymes https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3543

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem using `whereRaw` as `DB::raw()` or `DB::select()` can not `paginate()` the collection.

Problem:

Execution time: 11.449304103851s

`city_id = 6` & `$category_id = 1`

```
$stores = Store::where('city_id', $city_id)
        ->where('disabled', '0')
        ->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($category_id){
            $q->where('category_id', '=', $category_id);
        })
        ->orderBy('rating','DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Solution:

Execution time: 0.033660888671875s

`city_id = 6` & `$category_id = 1`

```
$stores = Store::
    where('city_id', $city_id)
    ->where('disabled', '0')
    ->whereRaw('stores.id in (select store_id from store_categories_pivot where category_id = ?)', [$category_id])
    ->orderBy('rating','DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Good solution :). Let me know if you are searching for a job in Gurgaon as an SE.

Comment: What I'm learning about whereHas is that we shouldn't use it... All questions related with this builder method are solved replacing this method for raw or whereIn instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running:

```
$stores = Store::where('city_id', $city_id)
        ->where('disabled', '0')
        ->leftJoin('categories','categories.store_id','=', 'stores.id')
        ->where('category_id', $category_id)
        ->orderBy('rating','DESC')->paginate(10);
```

and now verify your time execution. But you might need to add extra changes to such query because we don't know exact tables structure and how data is organized in them.

If it doesn't help you should get the query that is executed (exact query) and then run

```
EXPLAIN your_query
```

in Database Tool to show you what exactly is happening and whether do you really have indexes on everything that is needed.

Looking at your query you should probably have indexes for `stores` for columns:

- city_id
- disabled
- rating

and for `categories` you should have indexes for columns:

- category_id
- store_id

or for some combinations of those columns.